# looping to multiply by previous value in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a `DataFrame` in `pandas` as shown below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'origin_dte':['2009-08-01','2009-08-01','2009-08-01','2009-08-01','2009-09-01','2009-09-01','2009-09-01'],
                   'date':['2009-08-01','2009-08-02','2009-08-03','2009-08-04','2009-09-01','2009-09-02','2009-09-03'],
                   'bal_pred':[10.,11.,12.,13.,21.,22.,23.],
                   'dbal_pred':[np.nan,.25,.3,.5,np.nan,.4,.45]})

    bal_pred   date   dbal_pred origin_dte
0   10      2009-08-01  NaN     2009-08-01
1   11      2009-08-02  0.25    2009-08-01
2   12      2009-08-03  0.30    2009-08-01
3   13      2009-08-04  0.50    2009-08-01
4   21      2009-09-01  NaN     2009-09-01
5   22      2009-09-02  0.40    2009-09-01
6   23      2009-09-03  0.45    2009-09-01
```

I want to loop through and replace each observation of `bal_pred` where `dbal_pred != NaN` with `dbal_pred[i] * bal_pred[i-1]`. For example, the second value of `bal_pred` would become `0.25*10=2.5`. When `origin_dte` changes, meaning `dbal_pred` is again `NaN`, the calculation would skip the `NaN` observation and calculate the next `bal_pred`. So `df` would look as shown below. I have a while loop that does this, but the problem is it takes a very long time to loop through large data frames. Really appreciate a simpler/faster way to do this!

```
    bal_pred  date       dbal_pred  origin_dte
0   10.000    2009-08-01    NaN     2009-08-01
1   2.500     2009-08-02    0.25    2009-08-01
2   0.750     2009-08-03    0.30    2009-08-01
3   0.375     2009-08-04    0.50    2009-08-01
4   21.000    2009-09-01    NaN     2009-09-01
5   8.400     2009-09-02    0.40    2009-09-01
6   3.780     2009-09-03    0.45    2009-09-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# fillna with 1 so we can cumprod
c = df.dbal_pred.fillna(1).cumprod()

# track where null
n = df.dbal_pred.isnull()

# take cumprod where null and forward fill
d = c.where(n).ffill()

# cumprods divided by cumprod where last null
# gets us a grouped cumprod that starts over
# at every null.
# multiply this by `bal_pred` where null forward filled
# and voila
df.assign(bal_pred=c.div(d) * df.bal_pred.where(n).ffill())

   bal_pred        date  dbal_pred  origin_dte
0    10.000  2009-08-01        NaN  2009-08-01
1     2.500  2009-08-02       0.25  2009-08-01
2     0.750  2009-08-03       0.30  2009-08-01
3     0.375  2009-08-04       0.50  2009-08-01
4    21.000  2009-09-01        NaN  2009-09-01
5     8.400  2009-09-02       0.40  2009-09-01
6     3.780  2009-09-03       0.45  2009-09-01
```

Answer (score 3):

A different approach would be to label each group of data and then take the cumulative product of each group

```
group = df['dbal_pred'].isnull().cumsum() 
df.dbal_pred.fillna(df.bal_pred, inplace=True)
df['bal_pred'] = df.groupby(group)['dbal_pred'].cumprod()
```

output

```
   bal_pred        date  dbal_pred  origin_dte
0    10.000  2009-08-01        NaN  2009-08-01
1     2.500  2009-08-02       0.25  2009-08-01
2     0.750  2009-08-03       0.30  2009-08-01
3     0.375  2009-08-04       0.50  2009-08-01
4    21.000  2009-09-01        NaN  2009-09-01
5     8.400  2009-09-02       0.40  2009-09-01
6     3.780  2009-09-03       0.45  2009-09-01
```